# how to call a user defined function in matlab in another .m script

Tags: matlab

I'm quite new to MATLAB. I've defined a function inside a .m file, and I want to use that function inside another .m file. I want to run the content of that last .m file from the command window.

I have function `[feature]=hog(image)`. How do I initialize it in another .m script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly separating the function *definition* and the function *call*. The definition is inside the first .m file you described. It is important that there is only one function per file (excluding things like local, anonymous and nested functions) and that the file has the same name as the function. In your case, the file containing the function `hog` has to be called `hog.m`.

Inside the script, you *run* or *call* functions. Suppose you have an image `I`, you can call your function `hog` by writing e.g. `myFeatures = hog(I);`. Now you can work with the new variable `myFeatures`. Note that the script has to be in the same folder as the function (or the path to the function has to be added by `addpath('/path/to/function/folder')`. To call the script from the command window, simply type the name of the script.

**Example structure:**

Inside `hog.m` (function definition):

```
function [feature] = hog(image)
    % The code of HOG
end
```

Inside the script (e.g. `runHogDetection.m`), (function call)

```
% Read some image
I = imread('cameraman.tif');

% Get HOG features
myFeatures = hog(I);

% Do whatever else you need
```

And in the command window, you simply call

```
runHogDetection
```

Comment: Don't forget the matlab folder is already in the path (this is the one thats usually open  when yous tart the matlab program) . So if the `hog.m` file is saved in the Matlab folder it can be run from anywhere in the matlab environment

Comment: @hbaderts it is giving me an error saying undefined function hog for input arguments of type uint8